# Pandas data frames and matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have created a dataframe that looks like the following:

[image: Data frame #1]

I have no problems plotting the data with the following:

```
df_catch.plot(x='YY', y='ALB_C', kind='scatter', 
        figsize=(12,6), title='ALB catch/hooks')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('ALB catch/hooks')
plt.show()
```

There are many rows of data from many months and years.  I want to concatenate the data down just years (i.e. sum the month data per year).  I do this with the following:

```
name = df_catch.groupby('YY')
# Apply the sum function to the groupby object
df_year = name.sum()
df_year.head(5)
```

And this yields mostly the expected results except the YY data are now the index and any thing I try to do to get a similar scatter plot throws errors.

[image: Summed data]

Question 1.  Is there an elegant way to do the sums on they year data without getting the YY data as an new index.  Also note that the way I am doing this I get sums of all data columns like Latitude and Longitude which I would like to avoid.

Question 2. If you do have one of your data variables as the index, how do you do a scatter plot similar to the first code snippet above.  I was able to get a line plot using the code below but it is really not what I want.

```
plt.plot(df_year.index, df_year['ALB_C'])
```

Thanks very much in advance for your help.  I am really new to python/pandas but like what the functionality, I did go through the question search to find the answer and I have looked at tutorials on line.  Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For convert `index` to column are 2 solutions:

Need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
name = df_catch.groupby('YY')
# Apply the sum function to the groupby object
df_year = name.sum().reset_index()
df_year.head(5)
```

Or add parameter `as_index=False` to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
name = df_catch.groupby('YY', as_index=False)
# Apply the sum function to the groupby object
df_year = name.sum()
df_year.head(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:  Let's try

```
name = df_catch.groupby('YY', as_index=False)
```

or

```
name.sum().reset_index()
```

Question 2: Let's do this

```
plt.plot(df_year.index, df_year['ALB_C'], marker="o", linestyle='none')
```